# Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' has completed is not supported

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Update API Version to 33 and facing the issue while building app **Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' has completed is not supported**.

Gradle version 7.5.1
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",

i tried to update following version still facing the issue

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1')
classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```